# iPhone requests to php

Tags: php

I am working on the php side and my friend is working on the iPhone side. We are creating an app with friends and groups. I was wondering if it was better to use separate files for each task such as create group, delete group, add friend, remove friend or is it better to use  one update class that calls the necessary function.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: I'm familiar with how to use Post and Get i didn't know if  it was bad to use multiple files like addfriend.php, remove friend.php, delete group.php or to just have one update.php file that would have functions add friend and remove friend. Would the one file be hit by the user so much that it would be slow.

Comment: It would be best to logically separate based on your needs and preferences. For example, it may make sense to keep all CRUD operations of a single domain object in single files, it might also make sense to keep single CRUD operations of all domain object in single files.  It is really up to you....

Comment: @Crackertastic can you explain that a bit?

Comment: @user2872510 Yes, let me post an answer for it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two methods and personally I'd pick the first one because it allows me to be the most flexible, but of course the decision is yours to make.

1. **Get/Post to one file**

   You have one connector file that your objective-c application posts on, and then that connector file contacts your other files.

   An example of this flow might looks like:

   iPhone (POST request) `{'method':'addGroup', 'groupName':'My Group'}` -> `connector.php`

   Then connector.php will contact `groups.php` and run the method `addGroup`.

   For addGroup, you could have it use GET instead, such as `connector.php?method=addGroup&addGroup=My%20Group`.

   Of course, authentication should always be with POST, so you'll have to use POST for that and for more complex or larger amounts of data.
2. **Get/Post to multiple files**

   This could be a viable option too. In your document root, you would simply have all the file exposed such as:

   ```
   /htdocs
       /addGroup.php
       /removeGroup.php
       /editGroup.php
       /login.php
       /logout.php
   ```

   Then your iPhone app will contact each one of these end points.

In conclusion I'd prefer the first method simply because you are left with only one end point, this allow you to control which methods are available for the user to run.

Answer (score 1):

So first thing first, the organization you want is really dependent on the organization you need.  Everyone organizes things based on what they are comfortable with, so the question itself is a bit subjective. (Not to mention there are several ways you can go about this, again, all depending on your organization.)

One method is to put all your CRUD (CReate - Update - Delete) operations for individual domain objects (friends and groups in this case) in single files.  So in this case you might have files called `create.php`, `update.php`, `delete.php` and they might look something like:

```
<?php

class Update
{

    public function updateUser() 
    { 
        //code to update a user 
    }

    public function updateGroup() { ... }

}

?>
```

Your other classes would look similar.

You would then create a mechanism for deciding which type of object to run the update operation on, likely through parameters passed in your `GET` or `POST` variables.

Another way (and the method I would lean towards), would be to add your operations directly in with the domain objects.  Like so:

```
<?php

class User
{

    public function updateUser()
    {
        //update the user
    }

    public function deleteUser()
    {
        //delete the user
    }

    ....

}

?>
```

Hope that helps clarify some.  Again, this is a fairly subjective question, so it really depends on your coding and organizational preferences.